# how to display a image over other apps(like timer in YourHour app)?

Tags: java, android, permissions

I wanted to make an app that displays a image over other apps.
The best example i could was the timer that is displayed over other apps in YourHour App.
The timer keep track of the time I spent on the currently opened app.

[image]

But I really don't know how to start with the problem.
So, any type of answer is allowed.

**Other important things that might help you give a answer**

YourHour app takes two permissions

1. Display over other apps
2. Usage Access

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to get the process of the app you want to leech-on and then get the location of the window if present then offset your app from that window.

Some googling and you could get across some ideas [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4d60f5f1-add9-4345-a55f-676bf63e4e6e/vbnet-active-window?forum=vbgeneral)